# Why USB device Serial number string of Device Instance ID changes on Windows Virtual machine lead a device enumeration issue

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, azure, virtual-desktop, remotefx

We have a USB-based device that is plugged-in on a Windows 10 machine.

Following is the Device Instance ID of the plugged-in USB device under Device Manager:

`USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX\SSSSSSSSS-SSSSSSSSS` Where **SSSSSSSSS-SSSSSSSSS** is Device Serial Number String.

In this use case, there is no issue on the local Windows 10 machine. Device enumeration is successful using X Application.

Application enumerate usb device serial number before open the device for functional operations.

---

The issue with the use-case: **USB device connected with local Windows machine and want to use USB Device on Azure Virtual Desktop Machine using RDP**

We create an **Azure virtual Desktop machine**( Windows 10) and enable the ***RemoteFx*** feature on machines to enable USB device redirection from the Local Windows 10 machine to the Azure Virtual Desktop machine.

Connect local Windows 10 machine with Azure Virtual Desktop machine using RDP (RemoteFx).

The USB redirection is successful.

*USB Device is detected under Device Manager but on Virtual machine, USB Device Serial String is changed, Very strange behaviour.*

**Issue**: X application enumerate the device but parsing failed due to device serial number changed. Can not perform device open operation.

**New Device Instance ID**: `USB\VID_XXXX&PID_XXXX&REV_000X\\3&XXXXXXX&0&TSUSB-SESSION2-XXXXXXXXXX&3&XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`

**Is anyone know why USB device identification/Serial String changes of Device Instance ID on Windows 10 Virtual machine ( Azure Virtual Desktop)?**

I appreciate it if someone could help with this issue.

Read RemoteFX feature and Windows Virtual USB Redirection document but there is no explanation for this behaviour.

Read the same issue on other sites but no solution is available?

Comment: If the VID and PID numbers match then the driver should be fine. What is the actual problem that this causes?

Comment: @Mokubai thanks for attention. The issue is X application checks device serial number when perform device enumeration operation, here USB device is not open due to missing serial number string in parsing.

Comment: Why: USB connection identification is by socket ID. Azure server has server-side socket ID, not client-side socket ID, so it uses session ID and GUID to identify USB target. Windows client can use SN instead of socket ID, but Azure does not provide that.

Comment: I searched to see if Azure RemoteFX had a setting for USB serial number, but didn't find anything at all. I've only got experience with SN handling on PC's -- which also have similar issues depending on OS and settings and passthrough handling. I can see from the string that it's using session ID to identify the USB device tree.

Comment: @user165568, Thanks for the response and time. I did further investigation into the issue. TSUSB-SESSION2 string lead me a point towards USB redirection feature of MS that redirects the detected USB devices to the remote session. It creates virtual drivers and devices on the remote machine that mirror the USB devices connected to your local computer. I hope I'm moving in right direction.